# How to get data from Google analytics api v4 with access token in nodejs

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-api-nodejs-client

How do I get the analytics data from Google Analytics API(v4), I already have authenticated the user from Google now I have an access token how can I make a request to get the data from API, I am using Nodejs in my web server.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the Google Analytics Data API (GA4) to get the data (The API is in preview version at the time of writing).
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1

To Generate the report , You can use the Method: runReport (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1alpha/TopLevel/runReport)

POST https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1alpha:runReport

A Sample Body to Generate Report for  "screenPageViews" would be:

```
{
    "entity": {
        "propertyId": "<your property id>"
    },
    "dimensions": [
        {
            "name": "thereportData",
            "dimensionExpression": {
                "lowerCase": {
                    "dimensionName": "pageTitle"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "metrics": [
        {
            "name": "screenPageViews"
        }
    ],
    "dateRanges": [
        {
            "startDate": "2021-04-01",
            "endDate": "2021-04-07"
        }
    ],
    "keepEmptyRows": true,
    "returnPropertyQuota": true
}
```

To Get the property Id for your account ,  Use the Following endpoint (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/accountSummaries/list)

GET https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1alpha/accountSummaries

Make sure to enable Google Analytics and Google Admin Api in your Google cloud Console.